# Tags for Organizations

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we add tags to allow for users to ask questions of specific agencies/datasets?
(Sorry about the US Centric agency list)

- USGS - US Geological Survey
- US EPA - Environmental Protection Agency (US)
- EPA - Environmental
  Protection Agency
- NWS - US National Weather Service
- NOAA - National
  Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration (US)
- NCDC - National Climatic
  Data Center  (US)
- NGDC - NOAA National Geophysical Data Center   (US)
- NSIDC - National Snow and Ice Data Center   (US)
- NCDDC -National
  Coastal Data Development Center  (US)
- IODP - International Ocean
  Discovery Program
- NASA - National Aeronautics and Space
  Administration  (US)

Answer (score 3):

Tags are useful for allowing people to follow, or ignore, a particular topic.

[palaeobotany](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palaeobotany) is a great tag.

- It's specific - it's a narrow-enough subset of Earth Science
- It relates to an area of expertise, so someone who's an expert in the field, can easily find relevant questions.

When considering a new tag, ask yourself: firstly, have you got, or seen, questions relating to that tag? If not, then it is at least premature; and secondly, would it help people follow a particular subject that they're interested in? Are there people for whom a question would be of interest if it were about the US EPA, regardless of anything else to do with the question? Are there people who'd want to hide any questions that are something to do with the US EPA (because you can lower the visibility of particular tags, as well as increase it).

Remember, the search engine should pick up any of these sets of initials anyway. So it's easy to find posts that mention the EPA. Tags are for the classification of questions: and that's a different role than merely indexing references, because the search engine does that well anyway.

Comment: Recently, I communicated with SE staff about the homework tag. They pointed me to the [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) discussion, which seems to be relevant here as well.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect "no". These seem rather specific. There might be scope for a "data" or "datasets" tag... possibly best to see what need emerges though. IMHO.